# Can I throttle mosquitto so that no client may publish more than N messages per second?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I've been reading through the mosquitto.conf [documentation](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html), but I haven't understood if the broker can throttle connection attempts and publishing from poorly written clients, eg if someone writes a `while not connected { connect() }` or `while true { get_reading_and_publish() }` type routine. I'm running version 1.5. Is it possible with mosquitto to throttle connection and publishing on a per-client basis?

The mosquitto.conf documentation makes reference to the `limits.conf` file, but as far as I know this is only used to limit socket connections.

Comment: Several settings exist in the configuration file nowadays, such as max_queued_messages, max_inflight_messages, max_inflight_bytes. While these are not directly a solution to your problem, it should avoid too many messages being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run mosquitto on a private port, and a rate-limiting proxy on the public MQTT port.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I'll be needing HAProxy for this then.

Comment: nginx should work, but I personally have not tried it.